# Converting Timestamp observable to YEAR-MONTH-DAY format for polymer Dart

Tags: timestamp, dart, polymer

What the title states.  I am calling a cloud endpoint that records the submission time of a record as a Java Date.  When I call for the record form this endpoint it returns it to Dart as a timestamp which I have binded through polymer to a template.

However the Java Date is hardly human readable to non-programmers and I need a way to convert this in polymer to something that looks decent.  Any suggestions??

Thanks

Ruben

Comment: Ok, apparently an issue here is that the Java format of date doesn't seem to be compatible with dart's.  As I am unable to create a 'DateTime' Dart object from the java string representation of Java.Date I am getting back.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DateFormat](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/intl/DateFormat.html) class from the [intl package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl).

Comment: Arrgghh... can't get a question in here like I want.  Basically, I am passing this in through an iterable to polymer.  I would like to perform this conversion in the polymer template.  To use the above class I would have to grab it in dart.  The problem with this is that the class is an autogenerated cloud endpoint file and so will be a bit of a pain to edit every time the same thing every time i have to re-generate it (the Endpoint file).

If that is the only solution though, then it is what it is.. thanks!

Comment: timestamp = json["timestamp"].split('.')[0];  What I had to do to get the Java date to work in dart so I could use DateFormat.

Comment: You could perhaps change the format you get back from Java to get the _timestamp_ instead of the default `toString()` value and then use [DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/DateTime.html#fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch). If not possible, could you paste the Java date format you are trying to read?

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* convert a `java.util.date` to Dart.  The format you get back is not readily accessible to a Dart `DateTime` object.  Thus, in order to build a DateTime object in Dart from a java.util.date you need to do this:

```
var timestamp = "StringRepresentationOfJava.Util.Date".split('.')[0];
```

This will allow you to build a DateTime object then you can manipulate it in Dart with DateFormat.

However you cannot do this with Polymer Expressions.  So you need to do the work in the back, and then access it through a polymer property or function access when bound.